# Order function returns different values as vector

Tags: r

I want to rearrange this vector decreasingly:

```
x <- c(10, 10, 7, 3, 6, 2, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1)
order(x)
```

But it returns numbers which are different:

```
## [1] 10 12 13 14 21 28  6  7 20 26 27  4 11 24 25 18 19 22 23 15 16 17  5  3  8  9  1  2
```

Comment: Try `sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)`

Comment: Order returns permutation, not a sorted list http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/order.html use sor(x) if you wnat to sort out the vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` function returns *permutation*, not *sorted vector*:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/order.html

```
  > x <- c (3, 2, 4, 1)
  > order(x)
  [1] 4 2 1 3
```

The result (`4 2 1 3`) means that the *smallest* item is the 4th (that's 1), the *second smallest* is the 2nd (2)... and the *biggest* is the 3d item (which is 4)

if you want to *sort* the vector, use `sort` function:

```
  > sort(x)
  [1] 1 2 3 4
```

To sort in *decreasing* order specify `decreasing` parameter:

```
  > sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  [1] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`order(x)` returns indices of the elements of x in increasing order. You'll note that the smallest element of `x` is in 10th position in `x`, the second smallest (actually just as small) is at position 12 and so on.

to get `x` in decreasing order you can either use

```
sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)
```

or use `order` as an index:

```
x[order(-x)]
```

(why `-x`? Because order returns indices in increasing order. by flipping the numbers around zero you get the indices in decreasing order)